# Ключи между таблицами MySql

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.
Может кто сталкивался и сможет подсказать:
есть БД MySql в ней 2 типа таблиц:
1-ый - таблицы где лежат записи разных документов разных форм(на 10 разных форм есть 10 разных таблиц).
2-ой - 1 таблица, которая хранит список этих форм и их описание.
Нужно связать эту таблицу с другими таблицами: 1 запись из этой таблицы ссылается на таблицу формы т.е. внешний ключ ссылается имя таблицы.
Может я мудрю и можно сделать проще...
Думал внести в первую таблицу поле с типом формы, но тогда во все записи любой формы нужно добавить поле с типом и получится избыток информации.

Comment: А для чего планируется использовать эту связь. Ведь в обычных запросах вы все равно не сможете эту связь никак использовать. Имена нужных таблиц всегда должны быть написаны в тексте запроса и не могут быть взяты из поля другой таблицы. Так же нет смысла подклеивать к данным таблицы запись с типом, так как тип заранее известен на момент написания запроса (так как вы и так уже указали нужную вам таблицу). Так что названия таблиц вы можете конечно хранить для каких то целей, но использовать их внутри самой БД вы не будете и никаких ключей не надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас данные 10 различных типов документов уже находятся в 10 различных таблицах - у вас нет возможности ссылаться на них из посторонней таблицы как-либо иначе, чем через 10 различных полей, каждое из которых является foreign key для одной из 10 таблиц. 
В противном случае вы нарушите условие транзитивности данных (3-я нормальная форма), и если нарушение этого условия для неключевых атрибутов - в общем норма, то для ключевых недопустимо (представьте как потом SQL-запросы для выборки будут выглядеть).

Чтобы зделать красиво, можно добавить 11-ю таблицу, назвав ее например Document, в неё спрятать все эти 10 ссылочных полей, и на каждую запись в одной из 10-ти исходных таблиц сформировать (скриптом сгенерить) запись в 11-й таблице (в дальнейшем для автоматизации можно зделать триггеры на каждую из 10 таблиц). 
Далее на основании этой таблицы зделать view типа DocumentV, в которую спрятать всю эту ссылочную муть с 10 таблицами.

Таким образом для всех других таблиц и отношений будет одна таблица Document, для запросов выборки - один view DocumentV.

Comment: В том то и дело, что не нужно постоянно добавлять записи в 11-ую таблицу.

Comment: В том то и дело, что не нужно постоянно добавлять записи в 11-ю таблицу при добавлении записей в другие 10 таблиц. 11-я таблица просто хранит информацию(список) существующих таблиц, где находятся документы. Если в каждой из 10 таблиц будет добавлено по 100 записей, то 11-я будет хранить 10 записей, а если делать триггеры, то 11-я будет хранить 1000 записей - получается избыток информации.

Comment: в противном случае вам в каждой посторонней таблице придется включать все 10 ссылочных полей, также во всех SQL-запросах явно прописывать все 10 отношений. Тоже избыточность, и если посторонних таблиц со ссылками на документы много - вы получите еще большую избыточность.

Comment: А в таблицу Document можно вынести часть атрибутов общих для всех типов документов - там название, автор, дата - в каждого ж есть такое, в дальнейшем эти атрибуты можно удалить из всех исходных 10 таблиц, таким образом вы можете даже уменьшить избыточность.

Comment: Вы правы. Думаю надо подумать над изменением структуры ДБ. В любом случае спасибо за ответ.

Comment: а в PostgreSQL есть наследование таблиц - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/tutorial-inheritance.html ;-) 
Бросайте это недоразумение, переходите на PostgreSQL...